# Parametrize annotation value

Tags: java, annotations, compile-time-constant

I have two classes using annotations to define links between fields and database column names. These classes are very similar except for the column name they define:

```
class TableA {
    @ForeignName("IDTableA") // Column name in TableC referring to this TableA record
    List<TableC> elements;
    // Some other field definitions, common between TableA and TableB

    // Some other field definitions, specific to TableA
}

class TableB {
    @ForeignName("IDTableB") // Column name in TableC referring to this TableB record
    List<TableC> elements;
    // Some other field definitions, common between TableA and TableB

    // Some other field definitions, specific to TableB
}

class TableC {
    @LocalName("IDTableA")
    TableA refA;
    @LocalName("IDTableB")
    TableB refB;
}
```

I would like to have a super-class to which I could give the `"IDTableA/B"` constant. Ideally *"something like"* (I know you can't give anything else than types to Generics, but just to make my point):

```
abstract class TableAB<IDName> {
    @ForeignName(IDName)
    List<TableC> elements;
    // Field definitions common between TableA and TableB
}

class TableA extends TableAB<"IDTableA"> {
    // Field definitions, specific to TableA
}

class TableB extends TableAB<"IDTableB"> {
    // Field definitions, specific to TableB
}
```

Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. The IDName part needs to be a constant, and you can't provide a String literal as a generics type in any case.

Comment: OK then. I know you can't give anything else than types to generics, but it would have made sense to me "if" what I wanted to do would have been possible. I'll update the question to make it clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the problem comes from the fact that @ForeignName(IDName) needs a constant expression for IDName. There's no way you can get that constant expression to be somehow dynamic and depending on the subclass.

Comment: OK I'll find some other way around then. And wait the mandatory 5 more minutes before accepting your answer. ;)

Comment: @Matthieu No problem. I was just a bit earlier researching a related problem myself, so I knew that there didn't seem to be a viable solution to this. You also can't have an enum value in an annotation, since it's not considered a constant, even though you'd use it exactly as a constant.